# What's the best to include HTML tags before text produced by link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

basically I want the following output with `link_to`:

```
<a href="#"><i class="some-class"></i>Some text</a>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "#" do %>
  <i class="some-class"></i>Some text
<% end %>
```

Block form of `link_to` for the win!

Answer (score 0):

What about [content_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) ?

```
link_to "#{content_tag(:i, "", :class => 'some-class')}Some text".html_safe, root_url
```